# Change style/class with javascript on keydown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the style of an element using javascript on a keydown event. I've already done it with mouse clicks like this :

```
#mpc ul li:active {
 background:#844;
```

And these are the original properties of the element im trying to change:

```
<div id="mpc">

 <div id="wrapper">

  <ul>
   <li id="kickDrum_p1">1<p>Kick</p></li>
   <li id="snareDrum_p2">2<p>Snare</p></li>
   <li id="closedHiHat_p3">3<p>ClosHat</p></li>
   <li id="openHiHat_p4">4<p>Open HiHat</p></li>
  </ul>

 </div>

</div>
```

This is the original css.

```
#mpc ul li {
background:#999;
}
```

I'm really new to css/html and javascript and haven't started learning jquery so I prefer doing it all by javascript and css.

The idea is to assign a different key to every list item and when that key is pressed on the page, the list item's background changes, just like I've done the click event. The difference with the click event is I've made it so it doesn't follow the id's since you manually select the list item you want and then it changes it's style.

With key input however I need to specify which list item exactly I'm targeting.

So I think I need to create a new css class with the properties of the background I want the element to change to and using javascript to tell that when I press the 'H' key for example it should change the element's style to that and when I let go of the key to reverse it back to normal. If that makes sense. I do not know how to ahcieve that.

EDIT:

This is how I tried to do it:

```
var keypress = document.getElementById("kickDrum_p1")[0]

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
if(e.keyCode == 69) {
var key = e.keyCode
var color = keypress.getElementByClassName("color")
if(color.length !=0 ){
    cur = color[0]
    cur.className = " "
}

cur.className="color"
}

});
```

And in the styles I have this:

```
#mpc ul li.color {
background:#844;
}
```

Comment: I don't use jquery. I'd like to do it without jquery as I haven't started dealing with jquery.

Edit: I don't have javascript regarding that event. That's my question how would I make it change the style of the list item trough java script and css. What I can think of is creating a new Class of css. And using javascript to tell when i press the key 'h' for example that it should change the color of this particular list element and when I release the key it should revert it to the default.

Comment: You should at least show that you did some basic researches about javascript and events, what you have tried and where you have problems.

Comment: "..when I press the 'H' key for example it should change the element's style.." Which element? All of them, just one? What's the logic for determining which element is changed?

Comment: I'll try to add where I got with my javascript in a few minutes. As to  the logic. I'm trying to target 1 list element per key. So for example If I press H it should change the styling to the first element. If I press G it should change the second and so on. Also, important thing to note is , that I'm trying to make it so once I release the key it goes back to the default style.

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? The code you posted would produce an error like `'undefined'  is not a method` at the line where you do `keypress.getElementByClassName`.

Comment: why is that? I've defined the variable keypress already?

Comment: `document.getElementById` does not return an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<P ID="MyID" CLASS="Testclass">Test</P>

<SCRIPT>
Add here jQuery
$("*").keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which==107 || event.which==75){
        $("#MyID").attr("class", "newclass");
    }
}
</SCRIPT>
```

BTW: 107 and 57 are the K and the k in the ASCII table.

Comment: To OP writes in the comment: `[...] I'd like to do it without jquery`